# How to create a sequence of mouse clicking event

Tags: javascript, html

im implementing a game (this is my first game ever) so Imagine this.
I have 4 images (html5)
onclick they call a function that makes all the game to work!
So, in the game you have turns, the turn says to me how many clicks I will need in that turn.
So how to do it if I always click the image and calls the function and the user is just able to do one click while clicks should be equal that the turn.

Comment: Implement a counter and check it from within your onclick function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<img onclick="myFunction()"/>
<script>
   var clickCounter = 0;
   var turnNum = 1;
   function myFunction () {
      clickCounter++;
      if (clickCounter == turnNum) {
         // do stuff
         turnNum++;
         clickCounter = 0;
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: That's very useful! thanks for giving teaches to the noobs :D